# What are asynchronous circuits?

Tags: digital, digital-logic

there are combination and sequential circuits.In sequential circuits there is memory element used. is asynchronous circuit also used flip flop like memory element in circuit. and how they are unstable which make it poor choice for circuit. how can be explain the instability in asynchronous circuit?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are referring to a system that is clock driven. The data is latched at the certain part of the clock period (normally rising/falling edge). If you are using an asynchronous circuit, it can change its state anytime, including the data latch time. This leads to instability.

Comment: as both are sequential circuit so both must use memory cell ..... in asynchronous we use latch where no clock is used and in synchronous we use flip flop in which clock is used ... am i right?

Comment: Yes. I think that the best way is to analyze a specific schematics, if you have one.